# How to filter entire dataframe on boolean condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two date columns in the same dataframe. I need to filter the dataframe entirely if one set of dates is greater than or equal to the other column.

Example dataframe:

```
id    updated         compare_date
0     2018-02-10      2018-02-11
1     2018-02-10      2018-02-11
2     2018-02-12      2018-02-11
```

Code I am trying:

```
df_1 = df['compare_date'] >= df['updated'])
```

**Result I am getting get back is a boolean list** 
df_1 = `[True, True, True]`

**Result I want**

```
 id    updated         compare_date
 2     2018-02-12      2018-02-11
```

I have confirmed that dtypes are datetime for the date columns.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[True, True, False]` , and I think beginning parenthesis is missing in `df['compare_date'] >= df['updated'])`?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE is should be but not sure why its returning all True's

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be `df['updated'] >= df['compare_date']`, checking the `>` sign, updated should be on right?

Comment: you solved it crap. I am a dummy

Comment: np, we miss things sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to index `df1` by the boolean list that you created.

```
df1 = df.loc[df['compare_date'].ge(df['updated'])]
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   id    updated compare_date
0   0 2018-02-10   2018-02-11
1   1 2018-02-10   2018-02-11
2   2 2018-02-12   2018-02-11

>>> df.dtypes
id                       int64
updated         datetime64[ns]
compare_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

>>> df1 = df.loc[df['compare_date'].ge(df['updated'])]

>>> df1
   id    updated compare_date
0   0 2018-02-10   2018-02-11
1   1 2018-02-10   2018-02-11
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited my post to reflect that staging doesnt exist, both columns are in the same dataframe (df). 

When I run your line, changing staging to df, nothing happens in the dataframe no rows are filtered.

Comment: is your line using '.ge' to say greater than equal too?

Comment: Yes, ge=greater or equal.  Hate to argue with you but this syntax is correct.  You can reproduce the example I have above.

Comment: I looked in the variable explorer in spyder. I see that there is a timestamp at the end of the dates, do you think that is something that could be affecting your line of code?

Comment: Yes.  Suffice it to say something about your data types is probably throwing you off

Answer (score -1):

`filter(lambda df: df['compare_date'] >= df['updated'], dataframes)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got error 'TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str'. 

not sure why when comparing dates

Comment: just to clarify, in my example `dataframes` is your array of dataframes

Comment: I am new to dataframes but an array would be list of dataframes right? if so then no, just one dataframe.

Comment: @AnisJonischkeit, Always remember to add explaination to the answer you post, so the users can understand the use of it.